# Why we using super() when inherit is already enough

Tags: python, class, python-3.4, super

I saw an example that is about `super()`;

```
class Class1:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def name(self):
        return "My name is"


class Class2(Class1):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def name(self):
        return super(Class2, self).name() + " Tom"

#now lets call the object.
b = Class2()
print(b.name())
#Output is 'My name is Tom'
```

Here is another version of this one without `super()` that I made on the above codes;

```
class Class1:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def name(self):
        return "My name is"

a = Class1() 

class Class2(Class1):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def name(self):
        return a.name() + " Tom"

b = Class2()
print(b.name())
```

Output is same. So while we can inherit the abilites from `Class1`, we can use that abilities already. Then why we need `super()` ?

Comment: Your example is hardcoded to use a particular instance `a`.  What if you wanted multiple instances with different behavior?

Comment: Because `a` is mutable. If someone changes it, all your objects will stop working. awful lot of responsibility for a single mutable variable, don't you think?

Comment: @BrenBarn From examples, It seems like interit is enough to use abilities, so wondering why we need super()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using the wrong example.  Try to do this without `super()`:

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def square(self):
        return self.x**2


class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__(x)
        self.y = y

    def square(self):
        return super().square() + self.y**2


class CubeMixin(Base):
    def square(self):
        return self.x**3


class MultiplyDerived(Derived, CubeMixin):
    pass
```

**Edited** to use multiple inheritance, per chepner in the comments.

When `Derived` calls `super().square()`, it gets `CubeMixin.square()`, rather than `Base.square()`.  If it hadn't used `super()`, there would be no way for it to know that `CubeMixin.square()` even existed.

Comment: Replace `super()` with `Base`. To fully illustrate why `super` is useful, if not necessary, you're going to need an example that uses multiple inheritance.

Comment: @chepner: That's still repetition... if you need to change base classes, `super()` makes your life a lot easier.  It also passes the `self` argument for you, which is handy.

Answer (score 1):

What you did here is called composition, although you missed it by a little.

For large codebase it's generally considered a better approach, because it alleviates issues with debugging. Imagine you had a class that inherited a class which inherited a class... After a while it tends to get hard to keep up. Proper example of a composition would be:

```
class a(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

class b(object):
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.b = b

class rect(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.a = a(x)
        self.b = b(y)
```

Which seems a bit silly for something stupid, but has pretty much the same uses as inheritance. Additionally, it may take a bit more code (a decorator) to make the class instances not behave like objects so you don't bother the end user.

Get a better example, and comparison composition vs inheritance [Here](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex44.html)

Comment: The main reason inheritance is considered less flexible is the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), which composition is not required or expected to follow.  Inheritance still has its uses, however, particularly in cases where you want to write polymorphic code.